# I can't use PrinterWriter in my program, could anyone help me figure it out?

Tags: java

```
imageToPPMFile(picture,ysize,xsize,maxIntensity,fname);

}//end of main//



public static void imageToPPMFile (int[][][]image, int rows, int cols, int maxintensity, String fname) throws Exception
```

The `PrintWriter` that I'm trying to use here will not print the colours to the file 'fname' because the program asks for a declaration or catch as I throw the Exception above. The Exception however, was given to me by my teacher and so I need to keep it. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the `PrintWriter` and/or `Exception`?

```
PrintWriter outp = new PrintWriter(fname); 

int ysize = rows;
int xsize = cols;
int red, green, blue;
outp.println("P3");
outp.println(rows + " " + cols);
outp.println(maxintensity);

for (int r=0; r<ysize; r++)
{ for (int c=0; c<xsize; c++)
     {   red = image[c][r][0];
     outp.print(red + " ");
     green = image[c][r][1];
     outp.print(green + " ");
     blue = image[c][r][2];
     outp.print(blue + " ");

     }
    }//Adding a PrintWriter.outp.close() here results in the variable not being found
   }
  }
```

Comment: So, if anyone does come to the rescue, the exact problem is that my teacher told me to put in a 'throws Exception' statement, but that I don't have any idea how to use it. I've tried putting random catch and try statements here and there but as I don't know how to use those yet either, it left me quite puzzled. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "it does not work" is not a good description. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and then edit your post. You'll probably want to move your previous comment into the body of the post, and ideally come up with a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem. That short program may well not need to write a PPM file at all...

Comment: You should close your PrintWriter.out.close()

Comment: @Cylad: if it's just about how to use exceptions, you should start here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: @JonSkeet Let me rephrase that, it gives an error message saying that an exception should be declared or caught before it can be thrown.
 If I put in the statement that Yahor10 proposed, it tells me that out is protected in PrintWriter, so I changed the variable out to outp, but then it says that the variable can't be found, any obvious mistake there?

Comment: @Cyiad: Right - so include that in your post (but preferably the *exact* message), and trim down the large amount of code you've currently posted to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ok, better this way? Does it make sense now?

Comment: @Cyiad: No, it would still be better as a short but complete program. You don't need to add comments, you don't need to have anything to do with images. Did you read the article I linked to? (Sorry to be picky here, but being able to ask a question as well as possible is an enormously important skill, IMO.)

Comment: @JonSkeet So I read your article, and gave the information I would like to have if I was solving the problem. The main doesn't seem very important, so I just left it like this and about the imageToPPMFile, that's the problem and I need to do it because it's an assignment. So, could you help me nów?

Comment: @Cyiad: You've still included irrelevant bits though, and it's still not complete. The formatting is also unhelpful - why have you included the text part as if it's quoting someone? And where is the *exact* exception rather than your precis?

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you should `close` your `PrintWriter`. Call `outp.close()` in the same scope as you created the PrintWriter object.

As for using `throws Exception`, take a look at below example and you will understand it:

```
public static void foo() throws Exception {
    // Some code here. Possible occurring of an error.
}
```

To use this method correctly, you should call this within a `try-catch` block or another method that declares `throws Exception`. Such as from the below `main` method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Your other code

    // Call the method that may throw an exception
    try {
        foo();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
    }

    // Any other code you want
}
```